# App crashing while setting up click listener on button in dialog...

Tags: android, listener

Build a dialog I'd like add a listener, but the app crashes.What is wrong?

```
private void Info(){

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view).create().show();

        buttonInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);

        buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) { 

              }
            });
```

Comment: please share the crash logs... and how are you calling this info() method...

Comment: if your button is in layout info.xml you need to do buttonInfo = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the button is inside your dialog's layout.

If it's the case, try to replace

```
buttonInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
```

by

```
buttonInfo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
```

And you need to store the created AlertDialog (instead of the Builder) if you want to dismiss it after:

```
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(view).show();

    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);

    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: builder.dismiss(); does not correct: so I add "final" before AlertDialog.Builder and modify so: ((DialogInterface) builder).dismiss(); but nothing... crash again.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
 buttonInfo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
```

by

```
buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
```

final code

```
private void Info(){

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view).create().show();

        buttonInfo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);

        buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) { 

              }
            });
```

Comment: I don't think that AlertDialog.Builder class has a findViewById() method, does it ?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't... See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: 1st you try in your pc then tell me.